# Intellij IDEA resolve local require() path [ node.js ]

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I'm trying to avoid relative `require()` calls in my express setup. I'd also like to avoid placing my code in the `node_modules` folder. In short, I'm trying to implement any of the methods described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520).

Any of those solutions will work fine for executing code with `node` or `npm`. However, I'm trying to find a solution that will also be supported by Intellij IDEA's code resolver, i.e. trying to make sure "go to declaration" and autocomplete hinting works.

I've tried the following

- Setting `NODE_PATH` in the run configuration.
- Using a global prefix, i.e. `require( global.__base + "mylib")`.
- Adding a symlinked folder to `node_modules/`.

Adding a symlink from a `lib/` folder to `node_modules/lib/` does work, but comes with two caveats:

- Changes to the source files aren't picked up automatically, so I have to manually "synchronize" `node_modules/lib`, and
- When "going to declaration", IntelliJ (of course) opens `node_modules/lib/mylib` instead of `lib/mylib`. This can lead to confusion as the actual file and the symlinked file can be open in separate windows.

Instead of a different way to require local paths (all these methods do work with `node` after all), I'd be happy with a way to hint to IDEA that it should search the `lib/` folder for sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I realised that if you add a library through `Project Structure > Libraries`, it won't actually be enabled.

Instead, go to `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries` and add a new library. Set the framework type to `node_modules`, Visibility to `Project` and add your lib folder.

After adding it, make sure the `Enabled` checkbox is checked.

That's it, Intellij can now resolve your `require('mylib')` paths.

Use whatever method from the gist mentioned in the question to actually get `node` to resolve the paths.

Comment: It seems to lose the go to declaration feature, is there a way to get this back. I'm using import, not require.